# Javascript check div style then if empty then add text to div

Tags: javascript

Hi Have looked for a couple of solution but am stuggling as JS is not my speciality!

Currently, I have a div that is empty and hidden (produced but a BigCommerce generated page).  It's an empty div but has a class and is hidden via "Style display: none".

What I want to try and do is:

1. Check if the named div has the style of display none.
2. If above is true then check to see if the div contains nothing (empty string although would need to check as could be some whitespace)
3. If the above two are true, add some simple text inside the div and change the style to display (or remove the display none.)

The display: none style in the div is inline.

thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Does the DIV have an ID? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well seeing as you haven't provided any code I'll make some assumptions (you're not using jQuery, the style is inline) but you want something like this...

```
    <div id="myDiv" style="display:none"></div>
    <script>

    var theDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    if(theDiv.style.display == "none" && theDiv.innerHTML.length == 0){
        theDiv.innerHTML = "Some sample content";
        theDiv.style.display="inline";
    }

  </script>
```

In future it's best to add what you already have produced, otherwise you should rephrase your question "can someone please do this for me".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help guys.  I didn't have any code as with JS I wouldn't know where to start which is why I tried to describe in psuedo-style steps.  I also added it was inline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with **jQuery**. Add div an ID 'myDiv' and use following:

```
var contents = $('#myDiv').text();
contents =$.trim(contents);

if($('#myDiv').is(":hidden") && contents == ''){

    $('#myDiv').html('Here are new contents').show();

}
```